# PostgreSQL: changing password for a user is not working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

- I installed `PostgreSQL` on `EC2` machine and now I want to change the password of user `postgres`
- I do

> ```
> $ sudo -u postgres psql
> psql (9.1.5)
> Type "help" for help.
>
> postgres=# ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'newpasswd';
> ALTER ROLE
> ```

- Then I exit the shell and try to login with new password

> ```
> $ psql -U postgres -W
> Password for user postgres: 
> psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
> ```

My `PostgreSQL` version is

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.5
contains support for command-line editing
```

What is that I am doing wrong?

Thank you

**UPDATE**
I made changes in `pg_hba.conf` and this is how it looks now

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Then I restarted the `postgres`

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                                                               [ OK ]
```

I tried logging in again, but failed

```
$ psql -U postgres -W
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: Probably the old password is still stored in your ~/.pgpass file.

Comment: Nah, there's a password prompt there. I'm thinking the `pg_hba.conf` is set up in such a way that it's not accepting password authentication.

Comment: @willglynn, please check my update, it is failing again even after making changes in `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like willglynn said, it's probably your pg_hba.conf file.

If you have the following line:

```
local   all    all     peer
```

then change it to:

```
local   all    all     md5
```

That should then let you login with your new password (assuming that you correctly supply it) :)

Comment: Hi @David, I tried as you mentioned, but it still fails, please check my update as what I did, thank you

Comment: There's still a `peer` line that applies to local (UNIX domain sockets) connections from the `postgres` user. That'll fail unless the far end is running as the OS `postgres` user. See [the pg_hba.conf documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for a better understanding.

Comment: Although I was able to run `django manage.py syncdb`, I will still read about `pg_hba.conf` documentation you mentioned, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I just needed to add `-h localhost`

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to add that in addition to to changing `pg_hba.conf` file from

```
local   all    all     peer
```

to

```
local   all    all     md5
```

As per the accepted answer, the only way I could log in after doing the same thing the OP was doing was to pass the `-h` flag when trying to login.

```
$ psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

Hopefully, this will help someone in the future.  It was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

You have this...

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     md5
```

change by this:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
#local   all             all                                     md5
```

and restart postgresql service by

```
sudo /etc/init.d/posgresql restart
```

this work for me

Comment: When changing `pg_hba.conf` you don't need to restart Postgres. Reloading the configuration is enough. e.g. `pg_ctl ... reload` or `select pg_reload_conf()`

Comment: Just reload ... i did not know... thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was due to env variable POSTGRES_PASSWORD in docker container.

Answer (score -1):

For the folks, who are going crazy after changing password many times and trying everything mentioned here, remember to check user validity expiration. You can set it to 'never expire' like that in psql 9.x:

```
ALTER ROLE <username> VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

Comment: [This is the default.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createrole.html)